# How to start "In my time of need" having refused it earlier?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the beginning of the game there were two Alik'r soldiers in Whiterun inquiring about a redguard woman (who is Saadia in the Bannered Mane), but I didn't pursue the mission. Today, after many days of playing a exploring, I wanted to play that mission but the soldiers were gone from Whiterun.

However, I traced them to Rorikstead where there were interrogating another redguard woman who wasn't the one they were looking for. I walked up to them and they still stated that they were still "looking for a redguard woman". I rushed to the Bannered Mane to start the mission but Saadia doesn't wish to interact apart from answering "What's on the menu"?

How do I suppose may I start this mission, did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Since no-one answered, let me answer it myself which I found from internet research.

setstage MS08 10

This is a console command which allows you to start the mission and talk to Saadia.